# How to use exporting parameter with type ANY

Tags: generics, parameters, abap, rtti

I have a incoming deep structure in my recursive method which contains structures and tables, so I'm working with RTTI to check type, loop over it and do my operation, in case I found a specific component.

If the current component is a structure or table, then method calls itself.

Problem:
I import the structure with type any. So far so good.
And i want to export it as type any also.

And here I struggle.

How can I assign my edited deep structure to my export parameter ?

---

```
METHOD process_input.

DATA: lo_type_descr   TYPE REF TO cl_abap_typedescr,
      lo_struct_descr TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr,
      lv_comp_found   TYPE abap_bool.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_table>     TYPE ANY TABLE,
               <fs_value>     TYPE any.

lo_type_descr ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( p_data =  im_input  ).

IF lo_type_descr->type_kind EQ cl_abap_typedescr=>typekind_struct2 OR
   lo_type_descr->type_kind EQ cl_abap_typedescr=>typekind_struct1.
  lo_struct_descr ?= cl_abap_structdescr=>describe_by_data( p_data =  im_input  ).
  LOOP AT lo_struct_descr->components ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_comp>).
    ASSIGN COMPONENT sy-tabix OF STRUCTURE  im_input  TO <fs_value>.
    lo_type_descr ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( p_data = <fs_value> ).
    lv_comp_found = abap_false.

    IF  lo_type_descr->type_kind EQ cl_abap_typedescr=>typekind_struct2 OR
        lo_type_descr->type_kind EQ cl_abap_typedescr=>typekind_struct1  OR
        lo_type_descr->type_kind EQ cl_abap_typedescr=>typekind_table.
      process_input(
        EXPORTING
          im_input    = <fs_value>
          im_list = im_list
      ).
    ELSE.
      READ TABLE im_list INTO DATA(element) WITH KEY service_part = <fs_comp>-name BINARY SEARCH.
      IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
        <fs_value> = 'TEST :)'.
      ENDIF.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.
ELSEIF lo_type_descr->type_kind EQ cl_abap_typedescr=>typekind_table.
  ASSIGN  im_input TO <fs_table>.
  LOOP AT <fs_table> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_tab_index>).
    lo_struct_descr ?= cl_abap_structdescr=>describe_by_data( p_data = <fs_tab_index> ).
    LOOP AT lo_struct_descr->components ASSIGNING <fs_comp>.
      ASSIGN COMPONENT sy-tabix OF STRUCTURE <fs_tab_index> TO <fs_value>.
      lo_type_descr ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( p_data = <fs_value> ).
      lv_comp_found = abap_false.

      IF  lo_type_descr->type_kind EQ cl_abap_typedescr=>typekind_struct2 OR
          lo_type_descr->type_kind EQ cl_abap_typedescr=>typekind_struct1  OR
          lo_type_descr->type_kind EQ cl_abap_typedescr=>typekind_table.

        process_input(
          EXPORTING
            im_input = <fs_value>
            im_list  = im_list
        ).
      ELSE.
        READ TABLE im_list INTO element WITH KEY service_part = <fs_comp>-name BINARY SEARCH.
        IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
          <fs_value> = 'TEST :)'.
        ENDIF.
      ENDIF.
    ENDLOOP.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDIF.
get REFERENCE OF im_input INTO lv_cont.
ex_input = im_input.
ENDMETHOD.
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic export parameters are working beautifully:

```
CLASS lcl DEFINITION.
 PUBLIC SECTION.
  METHODS: process_input IMPORTING im_input TYPE ANY
                         EXPORTING ex_input TYPE ANY.
ENDCLASS.
```

So your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: If I try to assign the import variable at the end to the export variable, I get the dump OBJECTS_MOVE_NOT_SUPPORTED.

Comment: Then your import/export parameters [are not mutually convertible](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenconversion_rules.htm). This has nothing to do with generic parameters.

Comment: If you can create generic parameters, it doesn't mean you can convert anything to anybody.

Comment: Yes, you're right.What I can't understand is, that passing a table to import parameter type any works, but passing a table to export parameter doesn't work. 
This is the error message from dump:'Conversion of type "TABLE OF PRXCTRL" to type "C LENGTH 4" not supported.' Why is the export parameter type any defined as 'C LENGTH 4' ?

Comment: I could solve my problem by using CHANGING instead of IMPORTING and EXPORTING. But I want to understand this. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

> I could solve my problem by using CHANGING instead of IMPORTING and EXPORTING. But I want to understand this. Can you help me ?

I think you need to check whether you supply the `importing` parameter when you call your `process_input`. `OBJECTS_MOVE_NOT_SUPPORTED` will happen if you don't supply the same `exporting` type as your `importing` parameter.

Declare:

```
process_input
  importing
    !im_input type any
  exporting
    !ex_input type any.
```

How you call:

```
process_input(
    exporting
        im_input = ls_test
    importing
        ex_input = ls_test
).
```

One more thing i would like to mention that you shall not **DIRECTLY MODIFY** on `im_input` as it is protected otherwise there will be dumps.

you should declare `im_input` as value if you need to directly modify on it.

```
process_input
  importing
    value(im_input) type any
  exporting
    !ex_input type any.
```

Comment: I tried this in an empty program and it works with strings. I uncommented the whole code and only assigned import to export. It seems, that here is a problem with deep structures. Can you confirm this ?

Comment: I have to see your code. Could you please update the question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be outside of the code you quoted in the question. `TYPE any` only specifies that for the method invocation, any type will be allowed statically - you are essentially disabling the compile-time type checks. You still have to make sure that compatible types are supplied by the caller of the method at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is old, but go with: TYPE ANY TABLE as exporting parameter.